# How to fix VBA FOR EACH freezing at certain pages and not other pages of Word docx?

Tags: vba, ms-word, select-case

ISSUE: How to fix a Word VBA FOR EACH subroutine that seeks to insert a comment at each tracked change and, yet, will freeze VBA/Word at certain pages of a document and not other pages.

The below code works on **some** documents throughout the entire document. Other documents, unfortunately, will freeze at certain locations in the document.

I've F8 stepped through, for example, to find one document would freeze at pages 6 and 7 of a 22 page document. Strangely, however, I could run the code to insert comments at each tracked pages on all other pages.

```
Dim rev As Revision, txt As String
Dim pgno1 As String
Dim pgno2 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

'check Revisions
For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    Select Case rev.Type 
        Case wdRevisionDelete
            txt = Left(rev.Range.Text, 3) 'the deleted text
                rev.Range.Comments.Add Range:=rev.Range, Text:="Pg [#" & pgno1 & "] BLAH " & txt & " [ ... ]“
        Case wdRevisionInsert
            txt = Left(rev.Range.Text, 3) 'the inserted text
                rev.Range.Comments.Add Range:=rev.Range, Text:= "Pg [#" & pgno1 & "] BLAH " & txt & " […]”
 End Select
 Next rev
 ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
```

GOAL: Insert comment with specific text at each tracked change, throughout entire docxz

ERRORS: No messages. VBA and Word freeze, requiring restart.

Comment: What happens if you put a `DoEvents` just before `Next rev`?

Comment: What's on those pages? How do they differ? Put in some logging so that you can see *where in the code* it's stopping. Please describe "freezing" in more detail - is it possible the code goes into an infinite loop? Will holding down Ctrl+Pause break into and stop the code?

Comment: Thanks, Sam!  DoEvents was a great suggestion. It exposed the culprit location. 
Can one small sentence produce disproportionately high numbers of tracked changes?

Comment: Ha! I was about to send out the "Bat Signal" for Cindy Meister, Graham Mayor, Greg Maxey, and/or Doug Robbins. "Freezing" - Both Word and VBA windows stop responding, which requires restarting Word. F8 helps the most to identify the location of the strange/innumerate tracked changes. Thinking Out Loud: Can the tracked changes be limited to only text and not formatting changes? Should the FOR EACH loop through only wdMainTextStory and not other "story".

Comment: RE: "What's on those page?" The document has very simple formatting and text. It's akin to a main paragraph with subsections.